# {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameter: username"} in Keycloak Google Social login

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

When I login using Google Social login, I get the following error:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameter:
>   username"}

I followed all the steps shown [in this link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/social/google.html) of keycloak documentation.

I am using **Keycloak 4.4 Final** version and configured only fields of Settings tab in the **Identity Providers** screen of Google social login. **Mappers** and **Permissions** tab configurations are not changed.

I confirm that the Redire URI, Client Id and Client Secret fields are configured correctly and **direct_grant** is selected as the First login flow. Rest of the fields are default values.

Anything else that needs to be configured. Please suggest.

Comment: Your Keycloak was unable to get `username` value from the incoming Google token. It's possible to log the incoming token content via enabling a `DEBUG` logger `org.keycloak.social.user_profile_dump`. Using that info you can config a mapping of your Google token user name to Keycloak `username`.